# ANTLR4 no viable alternative; problem with spaces

Tags: java, antlr4

```
grammar Hello;

@parser::header {
    import java.util.*;
}

@parser::members {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    int A = 0;
    int B = 0;
    int max = 0;
}

prog
@after {
    List<Integer> msgs = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    Collections.sort(msgs);
    for (int i=0; i< msgs.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(map.get(msgs.get(i)));
    }
    System.out.println("Alice: "+ A +", Bob: "+B);
    System.out.println(max);
}
: stat+;

stat: message NL | message;

message: h=T_NUM ':' m=T_NUM ':' s=T_NUM 'A' ':' T_MSG {
    String msg = $h.getText() + ":" + $m.getText() +  ":" + $s.getText() + " A: " + $T_MSG.getText();
    int len = $T_MSG.getText().length();
    if (len > max) max = len;
    A++;
    int id = Integer.parseInt($h.getText()) * 3600 + Integer.parseInt($m.getText()) * 60 + Integer.parseInt($s.getText());
    map.put(id, msg);
} | h=T_NUM ':' m=T_NUM ':' s=T_NUM 'B' ':' T_MSG {
    String msg = $h.getText() + ":" + $m.getText() +  ":" + $s.getText() + " A: " + $T_MSG.getText();
    int len = $T_MSG.getText().length();
    if (len > max) max = len;
    B++;
    int id = Integer.parseInt($h.getText()) * 3600 + Integer.parseInt($m.getText()) * 60 + Integer.parseInt($s.getText());
    map.put(id, msg);
};


T_NUM: [0-9][0-9];
T_MSG: [A-Za-z0-9.,!? ]+;
NL: [\n]+;
WS : [ \t\r]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

Hello! So I have a task to write grammar and parser in ANTLR4 which recognizes this kind of input:

```
00:10:11 A: Message 1 
23:12:12 B: Message 5 
11:12:13 A: Message 2 
12:21:12 B: Message 4 
11:12:15 A: Message 3
```

and as an output, it has to sort out messages by time. Now my problem is with spaces. I want to be able to recognize spaces in messages but I get an error:

**line 1:6 no viable alternative at input '00:10:11 A'
Alice: 0, Bob: 0
0**

When I remove space from the T_MSG token and obviously input it works. But I don't know how to make it work for it to be able to recognize spaces in messages.

Comment: While I’m a big fan of ANTLR, I have to suggest that this could be handled very easily with regular expressions.  Is there some reason you *have* to use ANTLR to accomplish this?

Comment: @MikeCargal hello, I wish I knew what is causing this problem; i know that this error  **Indicates that the parser could not decide which of two or more paths to take based upon the remaining input**; but I really do not see where that is happening :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always dump your token stream to see what the Lexer produces for the Parser to consume.

For the first line of your test input, (using `grun Hello prog -tokens < Hello.txt`), I get:

```
[@0,0:1='00',<T_NUM>,1:0]
[@1,2:2=':',<':'>,1:2]
[@2,3:4='10',<T_NUM>,1:3]
[@3,5:5=':',<':'>,1:5]
[@4,6:9='11 A',<T_MSG>,1:6]
[@5,10:10=':',<':'>,1:10]
[@6,11:21=' Message 1 ',<T_MSG>,1:11]
[@7,22:22='\n',<NL>,1:22]
[@8,23:22='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
line 1:6 no viable alternative at input '00:10:11 A'
Alice: 0, Bob: 0
0
```

in particular notice the line

```
[@4,6:9='11 A',<T_MSG>,1:6]
```

Your parser isn't seeing the stream of tokens that your parser rules assume it will see.

This is because "11 A" matches the `T_MSG` Lexer rule.  Note: even though the `T_NUM` rule matches the "11" input, ANTLR's Lexer will use the Lexer rule that consumes the most input, so ANTLR will produce a `T_MSG` token.

That's why you're getting the observed error.

---

There are ways using Lexer modes, not `skip`ping `WS` (which means accounting for all places where `WS` can occur in your parser rules), or maybe a couple of other techniques.

That said, you're really applying the wrong tool to the job.  Reading this input in line by line and applying a Regex with capture groups will be **MUCH** simpler. There's nothing about your input that requires a full-fledged parser.

IF your push forward with ANTLR, you're probably also much better off just working out the grammar to get the correct parse tree and then using a `listener` to handle the results.  All of the `@parser*` , `prog {...}` and parser rule actions, are distractions at best if you're not yet building the correct parse tree.